# How to port WPF desktop application to web application?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, xbap

I have a `WPF` desktop application (using the `Prism` library) that communicates directly with an `SQL Server` in `Azure`. I would like to make this application easily accessible by users in my domain (not necessarily on the same network) without the need to install the `MSI`. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Preferably, the solution should work in `Windows 7` and later and/or in `Internet Explorer`, `Chrome`, `Firefox`.

Should I try converting the application to `ASP.NET` and run in `IIS` or is there a better alternative? I've heard of `xbap` but not sure it's suitable for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

[WPF app into ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809225/wpf-app-into-asp)

Having worked with both WPF and ASP.NET, I don't think you can just "convert" one into the other. Maybe some of the code (such as your Azure server communication feature) can be shared using assemblies, but you would still have to rewrite some (most) of it.